# Recommended target_include_directoriees usage and project structure with modularized, interdependent static library

Tags: c++, cmake, package, include, static-libraries

### Background

I'm new to CMake and while I've read through a lot of the documentation and feel like I understand many of the concepts (at least at a basic level) in a vacuum, I'm still left pretty confused when it comes to using several of them in tandem with a more complex project, one of which being target_include_directories().

### Current Setup

I currently have a library that I restructured and am porting to CMake that is a top level project with several component libraries/modules, handled using add_subdirectory(). The hope is that each sub-library will be usable as a CMake package component, and it is worth noting that some of the sub-libraries depend on others.

Right now the project is structured like so:

```
MyLib/
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── src/
    └── mylib/
        ├── sublibA/
        │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
        │   ├── classA1.h
        │   ├── classA1.cpp
        │   ├── classA1_p.h
        │   ├── classA1_p.cpp
        │   ├── classA2.h
        │   └── ...
        ├── sublibB/
        │   ├── (Similar to Above)
        │   └── ...
        ├── sublibC/
        │   └── ...
        └── ...
```

In my top level CMakeLists.txt I do

```
include_directories("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src")
```

So that when one sub lib needs to include headers from another it can simply do

```
// Arbitrary SubLibB source file
#include "mylib/sublibA/classA1.h"
```

I then use the awkward `PUBLIC_HEADER` property to provide a list of just the headers that are part of the public API (so no *_p.h files) for each module, along with `install(TARGETS ... PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ...)` to handle the .lib and public header structure installation. This is followed by some `INSTALL(CODE ...)`, which utilizes `configure_file()` to generate convenience component level includes in that same install structure (i.e. sublibA.h, sublibB.h, etc.) so that users can simply do

```
#include "mylib/sublibA.h"
```

to include all headers from that component.

This works fine for building/installing and results in a set of files that could be used as is; however, this has become a bit of a nightmare when it comes to packaging, as I would like to create a nice package of this lib that can easily be used with other CMake projects.

### Goals

- Have user's be able to access the library via something like `find_package(MyLib COMPONENTS SubLibA ...)`
- Have a unified public header structure so that a user accesses a class/component in code by (and only by) doing '#include "mylib/sublibX/classY.h"' regardless of which sublib it is, **limited by which sublibs have been linked to** (i.e. so "mylib/sublibB/classZ.h" is not found if the user hasn't done 'target_link_libraries(user_target PUBLIC/PRIVATE MyLib::SubLibB)'
- Same as in the above, have it so that in my build tree one of my sub-libraries can't find another sub-libraries headers if it isn't specified as a dependency/library link so that I know I have my dependencies straight (right now the top-level include_directories() just bypasses this requirement and later I could change my source so that one sublib includes the header from a new sublib, forget to update my CMake scripts and yet the build would still complete as if everything was OK
- Use propagated dependencies to avoid unnecessary linking/include directory specification by the user. For example if SubLibB depends on SubLibA, but a user of this library only requests the SubLibB component in find_package() and only links to it as well, have the linking and header inclusion of SubLibA handled automatically so no error is thrown on their end
- Be able to include a class's direct header file as if it was in the same directory (i.e. '#include "classA1.h"' inside classA1.cpp
- Obviously have no private headers placed into the lib's install/package

### Proposed Changes

From what I understand after doing a lot of research is that I really want to be using target_include_directories() instead of the top level include_directories(), primarily so that each component's `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` variable is populated and dependencies can be propagated. At first I was insure how to do this since only a directory can be specified and in my case this would errantly include private header files, but after looking over simpler examples, I think I've determined a general approach that might work:

New Structure:

```
MyLib/
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── src/
    └── mylib/
        ├── SubLibA/
        │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
        │   ├── include/
        │   │   └── mylib/
        │   │       └── sublibA/
        │   │           ├── classA1.h
        │   │           ├── classA2.h
        │   │           └── ...
        │   └── src/
        │       ├── classA1.cpp
        │       ├── classA1_p.h
        │       ├── classA1_p.cpp
        │       ├── classA2.cpp
        │       └── ...
        ├── SubLibB/
        │   ├── (Similar to Above)
        │   └── ...
        ├── SubLibC/
        │   └── ...
        └── ...
```

Then for a given module/component, lets say SubLibA (which doesn't depend on other sublibs) I do:

```
# Allow for including public headers in a given classes .cpp file as if they were in the same directory
target_include_directories(SubLibA PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/mylib/sublibA)

# Propagate include directory to dependents properly
target_include_directories(SubLibA INTERFACE
                            $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
                            $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
)
```

Finally for components that use headers from other sublibs (i.e. SubLibB) do:

```
target_link_libraries(SubLibB PUBLIC SubLibA)
```

If I understand correctly, this should make it so that:

1. Each module "advertises" its interface headers so that they're automatically included when linked to
2. CMake knows that SubLibB needs to link to SubLibA, and needs its public/interface headers
3. Because of my new structure and the way that preprocessors search include directories, any/all components a user links to with their CMake scripts will have their headers accessible in user code via '#include "mylib/SubLibX/[filename.h]"', as if "mylib" became one big virtual directory.

I think this usage of target_include_directories() also correctly sets up the public headers  of a SubLib component to be packaged when its target is EXPORTed, though I think a little bit more than that may be required to get the package config files to handle them (also how would I incorporate my generated headers into the package?). I'm a bit stuck on this specifically.

So other than the steps that need to be taken in packaging setup, I believe all of this will achieve my goals.

### Remarks

Are these change in-line with the intended use of target_include_directories() and the right direction to go in?

What else/differently should I do in order to achieve these goals?

I do have basic EXPORTs and cmake config generation present in my scipts, but I stopped working on them momentarily because of this issue. For very basic idea of how I set those up, this is what the top-level MyLib-config.cmake looks like:

```
include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)
find_dependency(Qt6 6.2)

file(GLOB AVAILABLE_COMPONENT_CONFIGS
    RELATIVE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/MyLib-*-config.cmake"
)

foreach(component ${MyLib_FIND_COMPONENTS})
    set(component_config MyLib-${component}-config.cmake)

    if (";${AVAILABLE_COMPONENT_CONFIGS};" MATCHES ";${component_config};")
        include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/${component_config}")
    elseif(MyLib_FIND_REQUIRED_${component}})
        set(MyLib_FOUND False)
        set(MyLib_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE "Unsupported component: ${component}")
    endif()
endforeach()
```

If necessary, I can host a repository of my source structure with just the CMake related portions for reference.

**EDIT:**
It's pretty ugly at the moment and only intended for personal use, but whatever (just no need to criticize the project itself :) ). Here is the library in question with the current setup mentioned: https://github.com/oblivioncth/Qx/tree/2183a1f7c64be090ebf1cf804a8ecf811d847658

Comment: There is no "ideal" project structure in CMake: the project's files could be organized in many ways. If your code works and satisfies your requirements, then it is good. If you have some **specific** problems, then as about that problems. Currently, "how would I incorporate my generated headers into the package?" seems to be the only specific problem. However, it is not clear why it is problem for you: generated files could be installed as usual, a directory with generated files could be added to the include directories as usual.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Perhaps ideal wasn't the right word. I more or less meant a structure that is as sensible/as straightforward as possible while also conforming to modern CMake practices, or at least will cause as little "fighting against the system" as possbile, for a library of this nature.

To clarify my current project satisfies only the last two bullets under the "Goals" section, but obviously my intent is to implement a solution that satisfies them all.

I'm more or less asking if my proposed structure and usage of relevant CMake commands will do this.

Comment: The usability of `find_package(MyLib COMPONENTS SubLibA ...)` (your first "Goal") should be implemented by checking `${MyLib_FIND_COMPONENTS}` in your `MyLib-config.cmake`. And it seems that you have that checks. Does them works? Usability of `#include "mylib/sublibX/classY.h` (your second "Goal") is seems to be achieved by your "New structure". Do you have problems with it?

Comment: it should be `target_include_directories(SubLibA PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include> $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include> PRIVATE ...whatever...) install(DIRECTORY include DESTINATION ...)`

Comment: @Tsyvarev When I originally posted this it was after trying several other changes that all had issues where they would help one goal while hindering another, due my requirements and the combination CMake facilities I need to use that I didn't/don't fully understand, so I haven't actually tried this yet as I wanted to ask about it first. Given your response and my needs, it seems like the right call to go in this direction so I will give it a try.

Comment: @fabian
Thanks for the suggestion of using install(DIRECTORY...) with the new setup, and combining the include commands. One question though: I know that PUBLIC populates the includes for the target and its dependents. For a target sub lib itself, I will only need to make use of the deeper include path ("whatever") provided in the PRIVATE section, as a module won't need to access its own public headers from the top level include directory. This is why originally I used INTERFACE for the first statement, as wouldn't PUBLIC add the top level as a redundant include to the target?

Comment: You should be able to make the decision yourself: Assume your public header files of the submodule are included in the implementation of the submodule: Do all include paths still work, if you use `INTERFACE` visibility? In that case you may use visibility `INTERFACE`. Personally I use the paths a user of a lib would use in the implementation of the lib.

Comment: @fabian Ah interesting, if I did it that way I wouldn't even need the PRIVATE section of the command as the include directory for a sublib would be the correct folder for the target and its dependencies, so just PUBLIC should do it. If I use INTERFACE in the way I described I believe it will work as I've envisioned. Using PUBLIC that way I don't think would break anything, it would just have an unnecessary include for the target that I'd prefer not to have if I'm being pedantic. But honestly I might try your approach where my implementation uses the same include paths as the user would.